# syntax error nextjs using react-testing-library and jest as test runner

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, next.js, jestjs

I am using react-testing-library and jest for testing in a nextjs project. But I got this error while running the test.
**Importing** things are excluded since stackoverflow calimed , there is so much code without details!

```
  x Expression expected
      5 |
      6 | describe('Page is working', () => {
      7 |   it('renders a heading', () => {
      8 |     render(<RootLayout/>)
        :                         ^
      9 |     const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 1 })
     10 |
     11 |     // expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
        `----
    Caused by:
        Syntax Error
```

jest setup below . I followed the official docs of nextjs.

```
// jest.config.ts

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const config: Config = {
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],

}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
export default createJestConfig(config)
```

and the jest setup file also implemented following the nextjs docs.

```
// jest.setup.ts
import type { Config } from 'jest'
import nextJest from 'next/jest.js'

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const config: Config = {
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],

}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
export default createJestConfig(config)
```

and the test file is here

```
// /home/raihan/Projects/Code/Blog/client/__tests__/profile/register.ts


import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import React from 'react'
import Page from '@/app/users/page'
import RootLayout from '@/app/layout'
describe('Page is working', () => {
  it('renders a heading', () => {
    render(<RootLayout/>)
    const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 1 })

    // expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()

  })
})
```

Why I am getting the syntax Error? why the **render** function is not working? I have searched in google and also stackoverflow but didn't get the correct answer.

Comment: I see your file is called `register.ts` when it should be called `register.test.tsx`. Note how I added an `x` at the and of the typescript extension? This tells jest to expect JSX inside that file.